# Simulate survival data from a Weibull distribution with both right and interval censoring

Tags: r, tidyverse, survival-analysis

I'm working with the following Weibull distribution:

```
df<-data.frame(y=rweibull(1000,shape=1.4,scale=70))
```

Now, I would like to create a dataset with both right censoring and interval censoring.

To add right censoring I selected a threshold of 150 and added a censoring column called "cens":

```
df <- df %>% mutate(cens=if_else(y>150,1,0))
```

Now, I would like to add interval censoring to the data, but I don't know how to proceed.

At first, I thought about adding and subtracting a random value to each `y` value:

```
y_upper = y + 5
y_lower = y - 5
```

but realized that when `y<5` this causes `y_lower = 0` or `y_lower<0`

Another alternative would be to remove all `y<5` values, but I don't want to truncate the dataset, because I want to use it to test a model.

Comment: what do you mean by interval censoring?

Comment: Suppose I'm recording the time of death of several trees. However, I can't visit the site where the trees were planted every day. Instead I visit it every week. In each week I record whether each tree was alive or dead. If I find a tree dead on week 5, but it was alive on week 4, I know that it died between week 4 and week 5. This is what I mean by interval censoring.

Answer (score -1):

You can simulate interval censored data by simply binning the values with a histogram

```r
y <- rweibull(1000,shape=1.4,scale=70)
histinfo <- hist(y)

counts <- histinfo$counts
left_interval <- head(histinfo$breaks, -1)
right_interval <- tail(histinfo$breaks, -1)
```